# Disable frozen string literal comment checking

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubocop

I'm newbie in Rails. I am using 'Rubocop' for checking standards, however I'm bothered with the way it checks the 'frozen string literal'. It keeps on saying on my files:

```
Missing frozen string literal comment.
```

Is there a way to disable the checking of this on rubocop? Or is it a bad idea to disable it?

I tried this on rubocop.yml but didn't work

```
frozen_string_literal: false
```

Answer (score 78, accepted):

This one worked for me

```
Style/FrozenStringLiteralComment:
  Enabled: false
```

Answer (score 40):

You might want to add the following to your `.rubocop.yml`:

```
Style/FrozenStringLiteralComment:
  Enabled: false
```

Is it a bad idea to disable this cop? It depends. You probably want to revisit this before migrating to Ruby 3.0. But because Ruby 3.0 will not be released soon, there might be more important things to do in the meanwhile.

Comment: It seems like Ruby 3.0 won't include frozen string literals by default, so it should be safe to disable it: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11473#note-53

Answer (score 5):

Adding `rubocop.yml` file not worked for me. It should be `.rubocop.yml`.

Create a `.rubocop.yml` file in the root directory of the Rails app and add the following code to disable `frozen_string_literal` check.

**.rubocop.yml**

```
Style/FrozenStringLiteralComment:
  Enabled: false
```

Answer (score 1):

Further to this, If you don't want any magic frozen_string_literal comments, you can use this:

```
Style/FrozenStringLiteralComment:
  EnforcedStyle: never
```